# How do you functional test an Android application fully using Robotium

Tags: android, testing, functional-programming, robotium

I am developing an android application whose workflow is spread across many activities.I want to test each activity for some particular user actions using Robotium.How do i approach this using Robotium, should i create a single test class for all the activities or should i create different test classes for different activities.I have tried the latter approach but robotium runs all test classes simultaneously breaking the app flow.I want the testing flow to be the same as the app flow.

Comment: How do you run the tests, from an IDE, ant, gradle or other? You may need to post the build script to get your question answered. I use your second approach of having one or more test classes per activity and they run one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague but here is my suggestion.

Test cases should be very small, you preferably want your test to only test one thing so that you know exactly what went wrong if it fails. Unfortunately this is an idealist view and unlikely to be the case especially with fairly slow UI based tests.

So here is what i recommend you do, I would create test classes not based on the activity they test but based around the functionality they are testing (this is probably pretty close to the activities though, e.g. login page) and then have a method in each that tests each requirement (e.g. failed login, succesfull login etc) but make sure that each test takes you back to a common starting point, in this case I would suggest the login page, that way your tests can run in any order and each one tests each individual test flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename your test method to have a flow identified by alphabetical order of the names.

For example if you have a login and then a checkin you could call the first test method test_app_001_login and the second test_app_002_checkin